# What is the use of db_datas column in ir_attachment table in Odoo12?

Tags: image, binary, filesystems, odoo-12

I am working on Odoo12, I read in https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/product_image_filestore/ that images are store in filestore in  later version of Odoo. i.e.9-13.
If that is true then why there is field db_datas in ir_attachment table. It is showing binary_data in this column. Although there is store_fname in this table having file path. Is odoo storing both informations binary form and filepath of image? Will not it increase the size of database?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***PGADMIN*** show "NULL" value of `db_datas` as "`<binary data>`". If you do "`select query`" or view this lines in **phppgadmin**, you'll see "NULL".